# Convert Boolean Values to Numerical (0s & 1s)

Tags: r, dummy-variable

To write my model in R I need to convert from group name values to numerical 0s and 1s.

Here is a sample of the data frame:

```
+------------------------------------+
|   state      ID   time    amount   |
+------------------------------------+
|1  open        1     0      100     |
|2  open        1     3      92      |
|3  open        2     0      101     |
|4  open        2     4      84      |
|5  closed      3     1      98      |
|6  closed      3     5      72      |
|7  closed      4     0      101     |
|8  closed      4     4      76      |
+------------------------------------+
```

To be able to write my model I need to convert the state column to be only 0's for "open" and 1's for "closed". It would look like so:

```
+------------------------------------+
|   state      ID   time    amount   |
+------------------------------------+
|1     0        1     0      100     |
|2     0        1     3      92      |
|3     0        2     0      101     |
|4     0        2     4      84      |
|5     1        3     1      98      |
|6     1        3     5      72      |
|7     1        4     0      101     |
|8     1        4     4      76      |
+------------------------------------+

Any suggestions on how this is done?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use a simple `ifelse` statement here:

```r
df$state <- ifelse(df$state == "open", 0, 1)
```

This assumes that the only two values which would ever appear in the `state` column are `open` and `closed`, which may be a good assumption here.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is

```
df$state <- +(df$state != 'open')
```

Comment: I never seen `+` used like this before, can you explain what it is actually doing here? is this better than wrapping that statement in `as.numeric()`?

Comment: thanks for sharing I did not know that was a property of the `+` sign

Answer (score 0):

Another base R option using `match`

```
transform(
  df,
  state = match(state,c("open","closed"))-1
)
```